# Difference and compatibility between AVR xxxA and xxx/xxxV series

Tags: avr, attiny, avr-gcc

*This is kind of two questions(difference & compatibility), but since an extensive answer to the latter will probably include an answer to the former, I think it's okay.*

Anyway, on to the question:
I've made a certain device prototype on a solderless breadboard using an `ATTiny13A-PU` (the PDIP8 one) and would now like to make an actual PCB with the SMD (`-SU`/`-SSU`) version of it (since the device is supposed to be watch-sized). However, the place I usually order my parts from only has the SMD version of `ATTiny13V` in stock. So, I'd like to know how those two are different and whether my code (in C) for the former will be compatible with the latter and whether that's true for other AVRs as well (for example, `'2313A` vs `'2313`/`'2313V`).

As for my own research, the summary sections of the respective datasheets don't seem to reflect any major differences and I'm not inclined to scan and the whole thing. The other thing I noted is that avr-gcc does not consider the `'13` & `'13A` the same MCU, so there definitely are *some* differences, I just can't figure out what they are. (while avrdude does, but AFAIK it only handles the uploading, not the code).

**edit/clarification:**
This question is mostly about differences in and portability of **code** for the A vs. non-A series (which do exist, according to avr-gcc). Listing other differences is, of course, welcome, but secondary.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I know, I answered anyway since the "V" suffix isn't explained there.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I feel that the question you linked is about general differences; whereas mine is focused mainly on cross-compatibility of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ATtiny13 is the original version and uses a different process technology than the ATtiny13A. The A-suffixed parts are fabricated with a low power process marketed as "picoPower", and the main difference is that they generally consume less power at the same voltage and frequency.

[image: ATtiny13A vs ATtiny13]

The difference between the ATtiny13 and ATtiny13V is more subtle. Unlike the A version, the ATtiny13V has the exact same die as a "standard" ATtiny13. The difference instead lies in how the parts have been binned after testing: V parts can only reach 10 MHz but will work at just 1.8 V, while "standard" parts can operate at 20 MHz but only go down to 2.7 V. The more modern ATtiny13A can go to either extreme.

[image: ATtiny13V vs ATtiny13]

The part of the product number that comes after the hyphen is just the semiconductor packaging being used.

Regarding differences from the point of view of code compatibility, I see no reason why the ATtiny13A would not be code and binary compatible with programs written for the ATtiny13. However, the **reverse is not strictly the case**: While the instruction sets and most peripherals are identical, the ATtiny13A has the extra registers PRR (Power Reduction Register) and  BODCR (Brown-Out Detector Control Register).
You need to check your code for any accesses to those. If I were you, I would make sure that all accessed peripherals still work identically in the ATtiny13, as the two chips *do* after all use different silicon and nobody can really guarantee compatibility.

Comment: Does that mean that there is, indeed, perfect cross-compatibility of code?

Comment: @FlashCactus Your code for ATtiny13 is perfectly compatible with ATtiny13A, but vice-versa is NOT possible as reasons given by jms

Comment: That's kinda sad, since I'm making extensive use of the power-saving features of the A (including the BOD-disable-while-in-power-down one). It's supposed to work for at least a couple of weeks off a 1225 cell (~50 mAh), and with the BOD enabled it 
gobbles up about 20 μA (vs. 4 μA without). Well, I suppose that means I'll have to try and find where to order the A.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing some hard core low level things. They are basically the same thing. The A, V, P, XX version are the improved version of the original, either lower power, more timers options, can run at lower voltages or other stuffs that is not that important in term of compatibility. See the datasheet for more detail. ATTiny13A is what I have been using because its cost vs functions is the best. Pu or su means only different packages, ie, su is smd, and pu is dip; When complie with avr-gcc, and just to on the safe side, I would set the device to whatever it's you are uploading to. The hex file should run fine on both device.